# will onblur event trigger when window closes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box and I have attached an on-blur event to it. I am using this to send an Ajax request when user focus on other elements in page. When user closes the browser or tab in browser, I want the on-blur event to also trigger. I don't want to use unload because it does not work in some browsers. Will on-blur event trigger when window closes or is there any method to send Ajax request when window closes.

Comment: No `onblur` will not get fire when window closes..

Comment: Even it would be fired, the way each browser handle the unload browser behaviour wouldn't make any workaround relevant as far as know

Comment: You are not going to be able to make the call. It is a race condition and the browser is going to kill the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, your on-blur event occur on the  "target" class of the element.

You could also attach event on the beforeunload method.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
$(".target").blur();
});
```

And The blur event does not bubble in Internet Explorer. Therefore, scripts that rely on event delegation with the blur event will not work consistently across browsers.

Please check

http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 1):

The onblur property can be used to set the blur handler on the window, which is triggered when the window loses focus. You can use something like this to get blur event trigger when user change window.

http://jsfiddle.net/xkDgQ/

**HTML**

```html
 <p>click on another window to fire the blur event for this browser window</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 window.onblur = blurText;

 function blurText() {
     alert("blur event detected!");
     // remove the event to stop an infinite loop!
     window.onblur = '';
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

No, only `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` are triggered on window close, and even then not in all browsers. Termination of browsing session is generally out of js scope of control.

P.S.: Even if they do fire, I don't think the runtime will have enough time or memory allocated to generate and fire an XHR object...

Comment: It does trigger a request, this answer is missleading.